# Is there any way to check if WorkManager is working properly?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

We can check if `Activities` and `Fragments` are working by opening and viewing them. But since `WorkManager` uses imprecise times and is more like a background service, the same approach can't be used here. How do I verify that the `WorkManager` runs and does what I intend it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could observe and monitor the state of your work manager. The work manager can be in one of six different [states](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkInfo.State).
According to official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation#kotlin),
You use the following piece of code

```
WorkManager.getInstance(myContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uploadWorkRequest.getId())
        .observe(lifecycleOwner, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
              if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                  displayMessage("Work finished!")
              }
            }
        });
```

For kotlin,

```
WorkManager.getInstance(myContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(uploadWorkRequest.id)
        .observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer { workInfo ->
            if (workInfo != null && workInfo.state == WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                displayMessage("Work finished!")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start a workManager class using the following method and can keep the instance of that also.

```
public static OneTimeWorkRequest getInstance() {
    if (workRequest == null) {
        workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(YourClass.class)
                .addTag("your_tag")
                .build();
    }
    return workRequest;
}
```

You can observe the worker using `getStatusById` and `getStatusesByTag`

```
WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusById(getInstance().getId()).observe(this, new Observer<WorkStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkStatus workStatus) {
                if (workStatus != null) {
                    Log.e("mylog", "onOptionsItemSelected: " + workStatus.getId() + " -> " + workStatus.getState());
                }
            }
        });

        WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusesByTag("your_tag").observe(this, new Observer<List<WorkStatus>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<WorkStatus> workStatuses) {
                if (workStatuses != null && !workStatuses.isEmpty()) {
                    for (WorkStatus status : workStatuses) {
                        Log.d("mylog", "onOptionsItemSelected: "+ status.getId() + " -> " + status.getState());
                     }
                } 
            }
        });
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the WorkManager testing artifact. You don't need to test `WorkManager`. You should be testing the interaction between your `Worker`s.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better solution than the other answers is to use the official debugging tools, like switching on debugging in the Application, using adb to get a list of jobs, etc.:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Switching on debugging:

```
class MyApplication() : Application(), Configuration.Provider {
override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
    Configuration.Builder()
        .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.DEBUG)
        .build()
```

}

Use adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler

```
adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler
```

Request diagnostic information from WorkManager 2.4.0+

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "androidx.work.diagnostics.REQUEST_DIAGNOSTICS" -p "<your_app_package_name>"
```

Or use the built in inspector in Android Studio under App Inspection/Background Task Inspector tool window.